# Replicate multiple rows of events for specific IDs multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, data-manipulation

I have a call log data made on customers. Which looks something like below, where ID is customer ID and A and B are log attributes:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'),
                  index = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D'])
df['ID']=df.index
df = df[['ID','A','B']]
```

```
  ID   A   B
A  A  46  31
A  A  99  54
A  A  34   9
B  B  46  48
B  B   7  75
C  C   1  25
C  C  71  40
C  C  74  53
D  D  57  17
D  D  19  78
```

I want to replicate each set of event for each ID based on some slots. For e.g. if slot value is 2 then all events for ID "A" should be replicated slot-1 times.

```
  ID   A   B
A  A  46  31
A  A  99  54
A  A  34   9

A  A  46  31
A  A  99  54
A  A  34   9
```

and a new Index should be created indicating which slot does replicated values belong to:

```
ID   A   B Index
 A  46  31  A-1
 A  99  54  A-1
 A  34   9  A-1

 A  46  31  A-2
 A  99  54  A-2
 A  34   9  A-2
```

I have tried following solution:

```
slots = 2
nba_data = pd.DataFrame()
idx = pd.Index(list(range(1,slots+1))) 

for i in unique_rec_counts_dict:
    b = df.loc[df.ID==i,:]
    b = b.append([b]*(slots-1),ignore_index=True)
    b['Index'] = str(i)+'-'+idx.repeat(unique_rec_counts_dict[i]).astype(str)
    nba_data = nba_data.append(b)
```

it gives me the expected output but is not scalable when slots are increased and number of customers increases in order of 10k.

```
  ID   A   B Index
0  A  46  31   A-1
1  A  99  54   A-1
2  A  34   9   A-1
3  A  46  31   A-2
4  A  99  54   A-2
5  A  34   9   A-2
0  B  46  48   B-1
1  B   7  75   B-1
2  B  46  48   B-2
3  B   7  75   B-2
0  C   1  25   C-1
1  C  71  40   C-1
2  C  74  53   C-1
3  C   1  25   C-2
4  C  71  40   C-2
5  C  74  53   C-2
0  D  57  17   D-1
1  D  19  78   D-1
2  D  57  17   D-2
3  D  19  78   D-2
```

I think its taking a long time because of the loop. Any solution which is vectorized will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
slots = 2
new_df = pd.concat(df.assign(Index=f'_{i}') for i in range(1, slots+1))

new_df['Index'] = new_df['ID'] + new_df['Index']
```

Output:

```
  ID   A   B Index
A  A  48  61   A_1
A  A  70  13   A_1
A  A  36  23   A_1
B  B  22  66   B_1
B  B  92  95   B_1
C  C  53   9   C_1
C  C  41  57   C_1
C  C  88  93   C_1
D  D  76  82   D_1
D  D  11  36   D_1
A  A  48  61   A_2
A  A  70  13   A_2
A  A  36  23   A_2
B  B  22  66   B_2
B  B  92  95   B_2
C  C  53   9   C_2
C  C  41  57   C_2
C  C  88  93   C_2
D  D  76  82   D_2
D  D  11  36   D_2
```